# elseif statement not working

Tags: php, if-statement

I have written some script that works great, BUT I have tried to add an elseif statement in which appears to do absolutely nothing, can't figure out where I am going wrong. (Yes I am a PHP newbie, but I am trying! :)

```
$i = 0;
foreach($arrJobs as $job)
{
    echo "<div class=\"job-ind\">\n";
    echo '<p><a href="' . $job->url . '">' . $job->title . ', ' . $job->location . "</a></p>\n";
    echo '<p class="smaller">Reference: ' . $job->reference . "</p>\n";
    echo '<p><strong>' . $job->salary . "</strong></p>\n";
    echo "</div>\n";

    if (++$i == 5) break;

    elseif ($i == 0) {
        echo '<img src="img/no-vac.png"/>';
    }
}
```

Everything up the elseif statement works perfectly.
Must be something simple I am missing or misunderstanding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basic syntax error ? you can't use the non braced short if's when doing an else if

```
 if (++$i == 5)  {
   break;
 } else if ($i == 0) {
   echo '<img src="img/no-vac.png"/>';
 }
```

notice the colour highlighting on this block compared to yours

Comment: really ? tell that to the 2.2 million lines of code in the current thing i'm working on.

Comment: Both work just fine no idea where you've seen that elseif needs to be combined into a single word it doesn't

Comment: Sorry, I just read up on it and it I guess stupid PHP made another inconsistency for the sake of simplicity *NOT*

Comment: Noticed syntax error on the foreach as well, should have closed that off before the if statement, works perfectly now.

Comment: There. Is. No. Syntax error. Questions of good practice aside, that brace block is entirely optional if you are working with single statements. If there was a syntax error, PHP would throw an error. Elseif by itself, alone, makes no sense.

Answer (score 4):

`$i` will never be `0` at this location.
You increase it in the if-statement before the test (`++$i`).

Comment: @MaximKumpan clearly not as he states my "bogged down syntax junkie" fix solved his problem

Answer (score 2):

[Note that elseif and else if will only be considered exactly the same when using curly brackets.](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php)

```
if (++$i == 5) break;

elseif ($i == 0) {
    echo '<img src="img/no-vac.png"/>';
}
```

Won't work, change it to:

```
if ($i == 0) { 
    echo '<img src="img/no-vac.png"/>'; 
}
elseif (++$i == 5) {
   break;
}
```

`elseif` vs. `else if`

I see a lot of people discussing this in the thread.
These are both correct and will both work.

The difference being :

```
else if() {
}
```

Translates to:

```
else {
    if(){
    }
}
```

And can't be used in code blocks using colons like this:

```
 if:
   stuff
 else if()://won't work
   //stuff
 endif;
```

Comment: would be elseif() if not using { } if using {} then its else if () (according to php website anyway) in my personal opinion if's should always run with braces makes it much easier to read and see closes etc since most ide's have brace highlighting.

Comment: I do agree that one should always use braces. IDE's usualy have the highlighting feature. Since many people don't use them who knows, people might still be coding using notepad loool

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working outcome, thanks for all your help!

```
$i = 0;
foreach($arrJobs as $job)
{
    echo "<div class=\"job-ind\">\n";
    echo '<p><a href="' . $job->url . '">' . $job->title . ', ' . $job->location . "</a></p>\n";
    echo '<p class="smaller">Reference: ' . $job->reference . "</p>\n";
    echo '<p><strong>' . $job->salary . "</strong></p>\n";
    echo "</div>\n";
    }

    if ($i = 0) {
        echo "<div class=\"job-ind\">\n";
        echo '<img src="img/no-vac.png"/>';
        echo "</div>\n";
    }

    else if (++$i == 5) {
        break;   
    }
```